# jQuery selector and DataPager cannot coexist! (ASP .NET)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, listview, modal-dialog, datapager

I am using a ASP .NET ListView with a MS SQL Database. I use the ListView to show the information and in the list view, there is an hyperlink which opens the editing window for the specific record in a jQuery Modal Dialog Box.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"> </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <!--More Items -->
    <a name="Link" href="EditItem.aspx?id=<%# Eval("articleid")%>">Edit</a> 
    <!--More Items -->     
    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SQL-SELECT-STATEMENT">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <div>
```

And jQuery works by taking the link of each item which has the name "Link" and associating it with a dialog box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[name=Link]").each(function() {    


            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href'))
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Edit Article",
                    width: 500,
                    height: 550
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything worked as it should. Earlier all the records could be shown in one go but as the number of records grew, I needed a paging solution. DataPager for the rescue!

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="5">
    <Fields>
    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField />
    <asp:NumericPagerField />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

But now the DataPager's controls are not working! I cannot go back,forward or click a page number as it will open the first data bound item's href in the ListView without a dialog box (Just like a normal page). But if i remove the jQuery code, the paging works as it should but I don't get the neat modal dialog box for my editing :(

Any ideas why these cannot exist with each other? Thanx a lot in advance :)

UPDATE: What doesn't work is that they cannot co-exist peacefully. If i remove the jQuery code, the DataPager works fine but I will lost my modal dialog box for editing. If i put the jQuery code back, the modal dialog box works fine but the DataPager doesn't :(

Comment: I don't see a pager in the posted code, can you post what *doesn't* work?

Comment: Sorry! See the edited code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that link selector is probably selecting data pager links. 
You can try `$("a[name='Link']").each(..` note single quotes around attribute value.

Alternately, why don't you use id or class selectors. For example:

```
<a id="editLink" ...
```

and

```
   $('a#editLink;).each(...
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply but sadly i tried both your suggestions `$("a[name='Link']")` and `$('a#editLink')`. I also tried class selectors but still the DataPager doesn't work as it should. If i remove the jQuery code, it works fine. According to my knowledge, I am not touching the DataPager's links but something else is happening.

Comment: You should able to validate if selector is matching with data-pager links by checking the match count [$("a[name='Link']").length] or returning true in click handler.

Comment: That was a great suggestion! It returns 5 which is the correct amount of tags that should be there (1 for each link!). So jQuery does not manipulate the DataPager's links. And to double check, i checked what links are being manipulated and they are the intended links!